# How to edit lotus notes multilingual database scripts

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a database with 2 languages in it but Designer only shows one of the 2 database scripts regardless of my client's regional settings...  I always see the same database script.

How to switch languages so the database script can be edited in the other language?

I have an English client.  The database is English and french.  I have set my client's regional settings to french as well as the default language in the DB, and restarted the client.... no luck...

Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "I always see the same database script". 
Are you trying to display information to the user in english/french, or what do you mean precicely?

Comment: I run a script on database open, in the database script.  I want my messages to be bilingual.  For the shared actions, if I switch my language in my Notes client config, I can get to the selected language's shared actions but that doesn't work with the database script.  I see that there are 2 with ScanEZ, so I ended up making the modifications there, but that is not a very clean way to do it.    Makes more sense?

Comment: Never worked with ScanEZ. 
WHat you could always do is store a UserLanguageDoc and use that for translation, if you translation code allows passing of the language.